# Get parentObject key in javacsript object

Tags: javascript

How do get parent keys in array using javascript here is the `Object` structure

```js
var JSONNode = {"sports":{"activityid":20,"Score":"240"},"dance":{"activityid":30,"Score":"260","missc": {"Study":{"activityid":90,"Score":"290"},"Cricket":{"activityid":30,"Score":"260"}}       }}


var overallItems = [];
function getScore250Plus() {
  for (var key in JSONNode) {
    if (key == "Score") {
      if (JSONNode[key] > 250) {
        // How do get dance,study cricket and so on
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Re the name "`JSONNode`":  JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. There is no JSON in your question.

Comment: `key in JSONNode` should be 'sports' or 'dance'.  Is this logic working?

Comment: What do you mean by "get parent keys in array"? What is `pp` in your example? Also note that `if (key == "Score")` will never be true in the given code, since `key` is property names from `JSONNode`, and those are `"sport"` (in lower case) and `"dance"`. The objects that `sport` and `dance` refer to have a `Score` property, but that's not what `key` relates to.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to get the names of the sports that have a score bigger than 250. Here would be a solution for that:

```js
const JSONNode = {
  sports: { activityid: 20, Score: "240" },
  dance: { activityid: 30, Score: "260" },
};

const get250plus = (data) => {
  return Object.entries(data) // Convert object to array of key/value pairs
    .filter(([_, val]) => val['Score'] > 250) // Check if the score of value is bigger than 250
    .map(([key, _]) => key) // Get the key of the pair for all the remaining items
}

console.log(get250plus(JSONNode));
```

Comment: You can leave out the `_` on both of those destructuring patterns: `[, val]` and `[key]` respectively.

Comment: Thanks didn't know the first one! But honestly I prefer to leave the `_`. Makes it more clear in my eyes @T.J.Crowder

Comment: Fair enough as a preference! :-)

Comment: @MauriceNino its working for me but what if there is nested Json structure

Comment: Edit the question and reopen it, or create another one. From what you are asking, this is the best answer I could possibly give you. @RaushanSetthi

Comment: @MauriceNino see the edit

Comment: Still not clear. What is your expected output? @RaushanSetthi